# What to do with a message/partial MIME type?

Tags: email, mutt, mime-types

I used a copier/scanner to scan a document and email me the resulting image.  It sent me several emails, each with a `message/partial` MIME attachment.  `mutt` doesn't seem to understand these messages. What do I need to do to these to get my scanned image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [uudeview](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/) for this.

First, save all of the emails into their own mbox folder.  Next, run `uudeview` on that folder.  When prompted, either press 'd' (for 'd'ecode) or just hit enter.  That will create a text file containing the all of the encoded data for the file.  Run `uudeview` on that file to get the image you want.

For more information about the `message/partial` MIME type, check out [its definition in RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.2.2).

Comment: If the solution above does not work, which is sometimes the case (maybe because of wrong order of messages within mbox?), I've found that Christian Herenz's solution below was still working.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I deal with such attachments in `mutt`:

1. I save the `message/partial` attachments in files named `part_01`, `part_02` etc.
2. I then concatenate those files into a single file, e.g. in bash

   ```
   for file in part_??
    do
     cat $file >> full_message
    done
   ```
3. Lastly, I run [uudeview](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/UUDeview/) on the `full_message` file.

   ```
   uudeview full_message
   ```

Notes:

- The only source from which I get these types of emails, are multi-page scans from "printer/fax/scanner/copier"-machines at my workplace (Ricoh Aficio MP C4501).
- The different "parts" are sent in different emails, with subjects `pdf copy from <printername> part <x>/<y>` where `<printername>` is the name of the printer and `<x>` is the part-number, and `<y>` is the total number of parts. Oddly enough, these emails do not arrive in a ordered sequence within my inbox.

Caveat:

- The "manual saving" could be quite cumbersome if you have many parts.  So far, I have never recieved more than 5 parts. Nevertheless, I'm of course interested in a more elegant solution.